# Flutter Redux Dispatch Action updates State, but doesn't update UI in Stream

Tags: flutter, redux

I have a `stream` that calls an API to receive data, each time I receive data, the listener `dispatch` an `action` to update redux `store` state (a list of items), state gets updated successfully.

This List of Items should update the UI once state is updated with the data came from `Stream`. That doesn't happen.

Here is a code sample:

My stream (part of a stream class):

```
  LoadLastDataStream () {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (t) async {
      _controller.sink.add(dataList); //StreamController
      UsersService.loadLastData().then((value) => dataList = value);
    });
  }
```

The above `stream` is being listened to by the following code, which updates the state, but NOT the UI:

```
myStream.listen(
          (dataList){
        if(dataList.length > 0)
          store.dispatch(new SaveLastDataListAction(dataList));//called successfully
      },
    ),
```

I think this is related to the fact that updating state frequently won't update the UI even in `setSteate()` like in [this example](https://gist.github.com/brianegan/42b7e2ef856ca8f82f84c62cba46b2d4). But I don't know how to fix the problem. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know anything about Flutter but shouldn't you somehow connect your component to `redux`? I can only see static (enum-) values in your example `setState`s.. I assume you would have to select from a store (kind of selector) class.

Comment: So when you "store.dispatch" gets executed, dataList updates the state. UI (ViewModel) gets updated automatically, normally, when the state is updated. 

In my case, my state is updated, BUT the VIewModel of my UI does not piick that as it usually does. I have to click somewhere on the screen like a button or so to be able to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no answers, so what I tried to do is to update any "other" value of my Store in order to trigger my ViewModel that a state has changed.

So for example, I had to add the following line:

```
myStream.listen(
          (dataList){
        if(dataList.length > 0)
          store.dispatch(new SaveLastDataListAction(dataList));//called successfully

          //I had to add this line to trigger my VM
          store.dispatch(updateOtherValueInMyReducer('any value'));
          //Only the above line is enough for me

      },
    ),
```